# i want to understand echedule.every().day.at how can it be in paralle with another thread

Tags: python, schedule

I need help please, I use schedule.every().day.at("17:40").do(my_function) and I would like my program to run normally and when the schedule.every().day.at("17:40").do(my_function) arrives, it executes the associated function but then it comes back in my loop and wait for another day etc.... I dont know how to do it because i think schedule.every().day.at("17:40").do(my_function) need
while1:
schedule.run_pending()
time.sleep(1)
So i dont know how to changes this 3 lignes to make my programme work.
Thanks!

Comment: run it in separated thread.

Comment: yes thanks but how i can do that please ?

Comment: search information about modules [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) or [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). There should be many tutorials (even video). And there is many question and answers on Stackoverflow.

Comment: but first you should check [documentation](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) because I found there [How to continuously run the scheduler without blocking the main thread?](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-to-continuously-run-the-scheduler-without-blocking-the-main-thread) - it seams they already put it in thread and you need to run `run_continuously()`

Answer (score 0):

You would have to run it in separated [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) or [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

But first you should check [documentation](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) because I found in `Common Questions`:

[How to continuously run the scheduler without blocking the main thread?](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-to-continuously-run-the-scheduler-without-blocking-the-main-thread)

They created class `Scheduler` which put it in thread and you need to run [run_continuously()](https://github.com/mrhwick/schedule/blob/master/schedule/__init__.py#L63)

But I use it to created shorter example

```
import schedule
import time
import threading

# --- functions ---

stop_running = threading.Event()  # to control loop in thread

def run_continuously(scheduler, interval=1):
    #print('starting loop in thread')
    while not stop_running.is_set():
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(interval)
    #print('stoping loop in thread')

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

# --- main ---

schedule.every(1).minutes.do(job)

# run schedule in thread
schedule_in_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_continuously, args=(schedule,))
schedule_in_thread.start()

# run other code

#print('starting main loop')

try:

    while True:
        print("other code")
        time.sleep(3)

except KeyboardInterrupt as ex:
    print('stoping', ex)

#print('stoping main loop')

# stop schedule in thread

stop_running.set()        # to stop loop in `run_continuously`
schedule_in_thread.join() # wait until thread finish
```

I use `try/except` with `KeyboardInterrupt` only to gracefully stop program when I press Ctrl+C - and code may stop thread.